# RCD spur to protect a wall light fitting

Tags: lighting

I have a wall light which is connected to a 13amp domestic ring main using a 5amp fused spur.
Is it possible to replace this conventional fused spur with a 5amp RCD spur for added protection should such a thing exist - I’ve only come across 13amp RCD Spurs.
If not, which is preferable to protect a light fitting in this situation - a conventional 5amp cartridge type fuse or a 13amp RCD spur.

Answer (score 1):

### I'd use a 13A max RCD spur fitted with a 5A fuse

What I'd do in this situation, since FCUs/"fused spurs" use BS1362 fuses based on my limited research, is take a standard 13A RCD spur and *downfuse* it to 5A by replacing the stock 13A BS1362 fuse with a 5A BS1362 fuse instead.

Comment: *How do you know all this stuff?*  ;)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- the trick is to read manufacturer lit (datasheets, install instructions, and so on) rather closely